# Power law of Pure birth-process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

Let $q(i,i+1)$ is a jump rate of a Markov chain from a state i to a state i+1.

Let $q(i,i+1)=\lambda i^{p}$ which has the form $q(i,i+1)=\lambda u(i,i+1)$
where $u(i,i+1)$ is the transition probabilities of a Markov chain at state i to an adjacent state i+1.

Clearly, for a Markov chain at state i, there is a finite time interval $T_{n}=t_{1}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+t_{n}$ that has elapsed.

It is claimed in the text *Essential of Stochastic Process* that the inter-arrival times $t_{i}$ is exponential with rate $n^{p}$

I am able to understand that the inter-arrival times between events are exponential. This follows from a definition of poisson process.

But why does it has a rate $n^{p}$?

Edit: Excerpt added.
[image]

Comment: It seems like the interarrival times should have rate $\lambda i^p$, from how you've written this.

Comment: @Math1000 Please look at the edited OP.

Comment: @Math1000 Reasoning from proof by contradiction, if the interarrival times t_{n} have rate $\lambda n^{p}$, then, by the law of large number, the expected value of $T_{\infty}$ does not corresponds to what the author has stated. So something is wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're at state $n$, the only possibility is to go to state $n+1$, and the transition rate from $n$ to $n+1$ is $\lambda n^p$, so the distribution of the waiting time until we go from $n$ to $n+1$ is $t_n \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda n^p)$ by definition.

In the text you're quoting, the $\lambda$ disappears mysteriously here, but reappears later on in the sum, which I assume is just a typo. We should have $E[t_n] = \frac1{\lambda n^p}$ and $E[T_n] = \frac1\lambda \sum_{m=1}^n \frac1{m^p}$.

Comment: The second part of your argument is what I had in mind. The amount of typos in this text is unhelpful.